# Как выделить даты в QCalendarWidget с помощью клика мыши и чтобы выделенная дата при клике второй раз на него убирало выделение

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, pyside2, qcalendarwidget

Я стараюсь сделать программу на *PyQt5*, где можно выбрать даты в `QCalendarWidget`, с помощью клика мышки по дате в произвольном порядке. 
Эти даты как-нибудь выделились (другой цвет шрифта, выделить рамкой). В моем случае, это маленький кружок сверх слева.

Но у меня не получается сделать так, чтобы после выделения второй клик по той же дате, убирал выделение.

Как выделить дату мне уже подсказали здесь же, но я не могу понять, как работает сигнал клика по дате, и метод `paintCell`.

Вот код, который просто выделяет даты.

```
введите сюда код
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QCalendarWidget, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate, QPoint, Qt
import sys


class Scheduler(QCalendarWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.events = list()

        self.clicked['QDate'].connect(self.show_date_func)

def paintCell(self, painter, rect, date):
    super().paintCell(painter, rect, date)
    if date in self.events:
        painter.setBrush(Qt.red)
        painter.drawEllipse(rect.topLeft() + QPoint(12, 7), 3, 3)
    

def show_date_func(self, date):
    self.events.append(date)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Scheduler()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Я пытался решить задачу таким образом: добавить в `paintCell` цикл,  который проверяет повторяющиеся значения в `self.events`, вычисляет их, и если значение делится на **`2`** без остатков, то срабатывает обычный конструктор который закрашивает по умолчанию. Но он не работает потому, что клик по уже закрашенной дате не выполняется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы дату, по которой кликнули, сохраняете в список `self.events`.
Удалите ее из списка если она там уже есть.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QCalendarWidget, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate, QPoint, Qt


class Scheduler(QCalendarWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.events = list()

        self.clicked['QDate'].connect(self.show_date_func)

    def paintCell(self, painter, rect, date):
        super().paintCell(painter, rect, date)
        if date in self.events:
            painter.setBrush(Qt.red)
            painter.drawEllipse(rect.topLeft() + QPoint(12, 7), 3, 3)

    def show_date_func(self, date):
        if date in self.events:                         # +++
            index = self.events.index(date)             # +++
            self.events.pop(index)                      # +++
        else:                                           # +++
            self.events.append(date)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Scheduler()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> Да этот вариант рабочий, но это работает как-то коряво. Сначала выбираю дату (дата отмечается) кликаю второй раз по этой же дате, отметка даты не убирается, потом выбираю другую дату, потом кликаю на отмеченную дату и только потом отметка даты убирается. Разве нет другого способа?

Да, все можно решить.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QCalendarWidget, QApplication, \
    QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate, QPoint, Qt


class Scheduler(QCalendarWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent                                        # +++ parent

    def paintCell(self, painter, rect, date):
        super().paintCell(painter, rect, date)
        if date in self.parent.events:                              # +++ parent
            painter.setBrush(Qt.red)
            painter.drawEllipse(rect.topLeft() + QPoint(12, 7), 3, 3)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() 

        self.events = list()        

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.scheduler = Scheduler(self)                            # +++ self
        self.scheduler.clicked['QDate'].connect(self.show_date_func)
        
        self.label = QLabel()
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.scheduler)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)

    def show_date_func(self, date):
        if date in self.events:             
            index = self.events.index(date)
            self.events.pop(index)           
        else:                              
            self.events.append(date)

        self.label.setFocus()                                   # +++       


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да этот вариант рабочий, но это работает как-то коряво. Сначала выбираю дату (дата отмечается) кликаю второй раз по этой же дате, отметка даты не убирается, потом выбираю другую дату, потом кликаю на отмеченную дату и только потом отметка даты убирается. Разве нет другого способа?

Comment: @catharsis я добавил обновление в свой ответ, проверьте.

Comment: Вы сделали колоссальную работу для меня, благодарю. Теперь мне остается сидеть с документацией и понять как все это работает, надеюсь я справлюсь. Еще раз спасибо @S. Nick